# How can I label my data in dict format to prepare for deep learning train and test?

Tags: python, dictionary, split, label, training-data

I have 3222 .wav data structured as below as a variable output :

final = {'a0001.wav':Numpy array, 'a0002.wav':Numpay array, ... ,'a3222.wav':Numpy array}

*All Numpy array size is 99X160

My question is how can I add the label of each .wav for example 'a0001.wav' label is 1 or 'a0002.wav' label is 0, etc.
And how can I split the final labeled data to train and test parts?

Below is the full code :

```
    import glob
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np

# Data augmentation

def augmentation(signal, split_size):
    split_signal={}
    split_list=[j*split_size for j in range(int(len(signal)/split_size))]
    for item in range(len(split_list)-1): 
        split_signal[item]=signal[int(split_list[item]):int(split_list[item+1])]
    Num_split=int(len(signal)/split_size)
    return split_signal, Num_split

# Variable defenition
aug_sig={}
final={}

aug_len=160

# Import file
files = glob.glob('*.wav')
for item in files:
    fs, data = wavfile.read(item)
    aug_sig[item]=augmentation(data[int(len(data)/2)-8000:int(len(data)/2)+8000], aug_len)
    arr=[]
    for i in range(aug_sig[item][1]-1):
        arr=np.concatenate((arr, aug_sig[item][0][i].transpose()), axis=0)
        
        
    final[item]=arr.reshape(aug_sig[item][1]-1,aug_len)
```

Comment: depends on the the package you want to use for deep learning. You could use sklearn, which provides you and train_test_split function (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) and a function for one hot encoding (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html?highlight=one%20hot#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder)

Comment: @Racooneer : I will use sklearn but the main problem is with the labels. How can I label all my data ? Should I add a label column to my 'final' output ?

Comment: If I understood corretly, the name of the ".wav" file should be the label? I don't really get, what the learning task would be then, but that's you business... My idea would be, to create a string column to your dataframe with the name during the for loop and this can be split with one hot encoding... that is the step that takes a column of categorical strings and splits them to several columns with the column entry pivoted to column head and entries are 1 and 0...